# Sublime text stops writing an output after a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, file, sublimetext3

I know that I can solve this issue by ending the process in resmon.exe. But is there a permanent solution?

Error -

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\C++ Programs\Data Structures and Algorithms/Rpractice.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Code -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Competitive Sublime/input.txt", "r", stdin);
        freopen("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Competitive Sublime/output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: How is that build error related to a segmentation fault? Do you try to compile while you are debugging the executable? Also please don't tag C language if you are using C++.

Comment: There error you are showing has nothing to do with a segmentation fault.  It's telling you it can't open the binary `Rpractice.exe` that you created.  Your antivirus might be blocking your program from running

Comment: While your program is running, you can't relink it because windows locks the executable. So spart from the virus thing (which is extremely common on Windows if you're using MinGW) you might also want to verify that the task ended if it actually ran.